# update value of jquery minicolors rgb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to set the default (starting) value of jquery minicolors colour picker but I cannot get it to set to anything.  I see lots of examples using the `hex` value but none using `rbg`.

I keep getting this error: `"Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined at updateFromInput"`

```
//this value comes from the parent controller and is an object
//scope.startColor = {r: 122, g: 134, b: 100};
var currentColor = 'rgb(' + scope.startColor.r + ',' + scope.startColor.g + ',' + scope.startColor.b + ')';


element.minicolors('value',currentColor);

scope.$watch('startColor', function() {
    var currentColor = 'rgb(' + scope.startColor.r + ',' + scope.startColor.g + ',' + scope.startColor.b + ')';
    element.minicolors('value',currentColor);
 });

 element.minicolors({
     control: 'wheel',
     format: 'rgb',
     inline: true,
     opacity: false,
     change: function(value, opacity) {
        var rgb = element.minicolors('rgbObject');
        scope.colorUpdated({clr: rgb});
     }
 });
```

Comment: `opacity: falses` , shouldn't it be `false` ?

Comment: yes, yes it should. however I still get the same error. thanks for spotting that!